# Largest A.C. frequency

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current

What is the largest possible frequency of AC that could be produced inside of an electric circuit (if there is such a limit). And what effects would such a high frequency have?

Comment: Would you please be more specific, perhaps with examples?  In other words, what do you have in mind by "AC frequency"?  Electrical mains?  Radio?  Microwave?  Light? X-Ray? Gamma Ray?  Something else entirely?

Comment: Google `electromagnetic spectrum`.

Comment: A note on the 'duplicate' verdict: this question asks what frequencies can be generated in an AC circuit, which is not as large a range as the entire EM spectrum.